# What is the alternative of filter context missing clause in elastic search 8.9?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

The same syntax below has been working in 2.3 v and if I do execute it in 8.9v does not work.

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
    "bool": {
    "filter": [
                {
                    "missing": { //"reason": "unknown field [missing]"
                        "field": "lst_act_date"
                    }
                }
            ]
           }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `missing` query has been [deprecated in ES 2.2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/release-notes-2.2.0.html#deprecation-2.2.0). You now need to use the `bool/must_not/exists` combo:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "lst_act_date"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "lst_act_date"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Even with filter/bool/must_not/exists works.

Comment: What do you mean by "Even with filter/bool/must_not/exists works." ? Works or doesn't?

Comment: can we write it the other way also as I mentioned?

Comment: it works, but it makes no sense to add a must_not inside a filter... [must_not already executes in the filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context), which is what my answer refers to

Comment: Got it will stick with your direction.